# How to get all apps to show in shell:AppsFolder when using Shell Launcher V2 to launch a custom shell app?

Tags: windows, shell, windows-11

I used Shell Launcher V2 to set up a custom app (win32, not UWP) to run as shell on a machine running Windows 11 Enterprise. This works fine but I need to launch another win32 app from the shell app. Normally, I use the shell:AppsFolder to get the AUMID of the other app and launch it.

The problem is that shell:AppsFolder only shows UWP apps when using the custom shell, whereas when running normally (i.e. with normal explorer shell), I get all installed programs (UWP or otherwise) in the shell:AppsFolder.

How can I configure Shell Launcher V2 so that I get all of the installed apps when running with the custom shell and not just the UWP apps?

Edit: After playing around with the shell some more, I got it to a point where it updated. Among the things I tried was running the windows update troubleshooter, the windows store troubleshooter, I repaired and reset the store app and added a microsoft account.

Not sure which of these actions caused it but now shell:AppsFolder shows all apps. However, installing an app or removing an app, be it a UWP app or win32 app, shell:AppsFolder doesn't react.

I also tried other things to see if I can get the AUMID some other ways and what I discovered was that running `Get-StartApps` or `Get-AppxPackage` in Powershell also doesn't list newly installed apps, UWP or otherwise, whereas when running with explorer as shell, they do.

It's as if Windows isn't aware of app installations/removal at all when using a custom shell. Is there a service or something that isn't running which tells windows when apps get installed/removed?

Comment: So `shell:AppsFolder` is just a flattened combination of the system and current user's start menu folders (`%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu` and `C:\programdata\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu`) plus windows store apps. The windows start menu stuff is pretty tightly integrated with the explorer.exe shell, so it wouldn't surprise me that it doesn't update with a different shell. What are you looking for, just the path to a specific win32 executable?

Comment: @Cpt.Whale Yeah, but not necessarily win32. UWP apps as well. If all I needed was win32, I wouldn't have bothered with V2 and just stuck with Shell Launcher V1.

Answer (score 0):

Try out some of these - I'm not sure what all gets updated when the shell isn't really running:

```sh
# List the package class names for the user from the registry 
# these should be closest to the actual packages list, but don't have ID as a property
$ActivatableClasses = (Get-ChildItem 'HKCU:\Software\Classes\ActivatableClasses\Package\').PSChildName

# this should get all the actual AppX AUMIDs
$AppxClasses = (Get-ItemProperty 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Classes\AppX*\Application').AppUserModelID

# starts a new shell com instance and asks it for the appx ID list - likely the same result as shell:AppsFolder
$ApplicationIDs = (New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).NameSpace('shell:::{4234d49b-0245-4df3-b780-3893943456e1}').Items() | % path

# more of a .net-specific way to do Get-AppxPackage
$packages = [Windows.Management.Deployment.PackageManager]::new().FindPackagesForUser("")
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I don't seem to have a ActivatableClasses key on that path. The second registry path is either incomplete or isn't getting updated, not sure which. The third option shows the same results as shell:AppsFolder. I couldn't get [Windows.Management.Deployment.PackageManager] to work from powershell so will make a test exe app to try it out.

Comment: @user1969903 just to make sure, are you running all this stuff as the current logged on user, and not as Admin/System/whatever the shell runs as?

Comment: I am running as the user that the shell laucnher is configured for. The user is in administrator goup and powershell was started with admin rights

Comment: Ok, just tried running FindPackagesForUser from a console app and it doesn't list the newly installed apps either. There has to be some service or some flag to run explorer with that refreshes the list of apps...